# Is there a way to highlight whole words with "Ctrl-Shift-(Arrow Keys)" in the Ubuntu WSL?

Tags: shell, zsh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm running the Ubuntu WSL with the Windows Terminal and am having trouble highlighting words with "Ctrl-Shift-(Arrow Keys)". In PowerShell (and any graphical application I've tried on Windows 10) This key combination let's me highlight words in either direction. I can also traverse words with just "Ctrl-(Arrow Keys)". That much works in the Ubuntu WSL as well. I already have PSReadLine, which I believe is needed to get even the functionality that I already have. I'd like to be able to highlight words in the Ubuntu WSL session with "Ctrl-Shift", but it seems the shell or something reads the arrow keys as "A"s and "D"s instead. Is there a way to get this feature?

Comment: What do you mean by "highlight", i.e. what effect you want to actually see, when you press this key combination? Anything which has to do with changing the appearance of the text in a terminal, depends on the terminal program; the best a shell can do is sending suitable escape codes to the terminal, if the terminal supports this capability. In the case of zsh, this would relate to the zle (Z-shell line editor), but you also tagged your question as 'shell' (i.e. POSIX shell), and POSIX shell bey default has no such feature.

Comment: So, what program is exactly the _Windows Terminal_ you are talking about, and what is the content of your `TERM` variable?

Comment: for anyone stumbling on this, I believe this is not supported (yet) https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/715

Answer (score 0):

There is as of this issue being closed:

https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/pull/13053

ctrl+shift+m to enter mark mode